# do you make request of type "post" when you only have one key sent in params? (best practice)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i need to make a request which add data to the database, so i think it make sense to make it a post request, but i have only one key which is the id field i want to send, should i send it as params or in the body? also if i send it with params should it still be a post request, since it will have no body?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When do you use POST and when do you use GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get)

Comment: @SMAKSS not entirly, i understand i need to use post, because i add data, but should i send the data through url params or body?